# Cannot select in SQL Server CE

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am having the following exception when selecting in SQL Server CE

ex = {" [ 1,24,) ]"}, code :

```
 Try
        Dim con As SqlCeConnection = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" & data_base)
        cmd = New SqlCeCommand("select * from Inventory)", con)

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

Error:

> StackTrace:
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at Bestseller.Scan.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
>   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog(IntPtr hwnModal)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
>   at Bestseller.MainForm.strtscan_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
>   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
>   at Bestseller.MainForm.Main()

Knowing that I can insert to the table normally.

Would you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You select statement has an extra parenthesis:

```
cmd = New SqlCeCommand("select * from Inventory)", con)
```

Try to use

```
cmd = New SqlCeCommand("select * from Inventory", con)
```

Instead